# Why is counting to a billion in lisp so slow?

Tags: windows, while-loop, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun billion-test () 
  (setq i 0) 
  (loop while (< i 100) do 
    (setq i (+ i 1)))) 
(billion-test) 
(print "done")
```

I have the above `Lisp` code that simply loops to one billion. The problem is it is really
slow. Slower than any trivial program I have ever written. These are the times it took to
run with the intepreters I have(gcl and clisp).

```
                       Compiled  Uncompiled
GNU Common Lisp(gcl)    270-300s  900-960s
Clisp                   280-300s  960-1647s
```

I used this Python code to time the time for `Clisp` and an approximated using the system time
with `gcl` since you can't run it from the command prompt.

```
import sys
import time
import os

start=time.time()
os.system(" ".join(sys.argv[1:]))
stop=time.time()

print "\n%.4f seconds\n"%(stop-start)
```

Here are the comparison with while loops from other languages:

```
Kawa scheme     220.3350s
Petite chez     112.827s
C#              1.9130s
Ruby            31.045s
Python          116.8600s        113.7090s(optimized)
C               2.8240s          0.0150s(optimized)
lua             84.6970s
```

My assumption is that `loop while <condition> do` is the `Lisp` equivalent of a `while`
loop. I have some doubts about those `1647s(25+ min)`, I was watching something at that
time and it might have slowed the execution, but by almost `800s`? I don't know.
These results are hard to believe. According to [Norvig](http://norvig.com/python-lisp.html) `Lisp`
is 3 to 85 times faster than `Python`. Judging from what I got, the most logical
explanation for such slow execution is that `Clisp` and `gcl` in `Windows` have some kind
of bug that slows down large iterations. How, you ask, I don't know?
Sooo, my question is, **why so slow**?
**Is anybody else getting something like this?**

**UPDATE 1:**
I ran Joswigs's program and got these results:

```
      compiled   uncompiled
gcl    0.8s       12mins
clisp  5mins      18mins
```

`gcl` compiled the program fine, `clisp` however gave this warning:

```
;; Compiling file C:\mine\.cl\test.cl ...
WARNING: in BILLION-TEST in lines 1..8 : FIXNUM-SAFETY is not a 
valid OPTIMIZE quality.
 0 errors, 1 warning
;; Wrote file C:\mine\.cl\test.fas

     ;; clisp
     [2]> (type-of 1000000000)
     (INTEGER (16777215))

     ;;gcl
     (type-of 1000000000)
      FIXNUM
```

Guess that could be the reason it took more than a minute.

**UPDATE 2:**
I thought I would give it another try with another implementation just to confirm
that it's really the `bignum` comparison that slowing it down. I obtained `sbcl`
for windows and ran the program again:

```
 * (print most-positive-fixnum)
   536870911

 * (compile-file "count-to-billion.cl")
   ; compiling file "C:/mine/.cl/count-to-billion.cl"
   (written 09 OCT 2013 04:28:24 PM):
   ; compiling (DEFUN BILLION-TEST ...)
   ; file: C:/mine/.cl/count-to-billion.cl
   ; in: DEFUN BILLION-TEST
   ;     (OPTIMIZE (SPEED 3) (SAFETY 0) (DEBUG 0) (FIXNUM-SAFETY 0))
   ;
   ; caught WARNING:
   ;   Ignoring unknown optimization quality FIXNUM-SAFETY in:
   ;    (OPTIMIZE (SPEED 3) (SAFETY 0) (DEBUG 0) (FIXNUM-SAFETY 0))

 * (load "count-to-billion")
```

I wish I could tell you how long it took but I never saw the end of it. I waited for
2 hours, watched an episode of Vampire Diaries(hehe) and it still hadn't finished.
I was expecting it to be faster than `Clisp` since its `MOST-POSITIVE-FIXNUM` is, well, more
positive. I'm vouching for the slow implementation point because only `gcl` could pull
off the less than one minute run.

Running Rörd's code with `gcl`:

```
(time (loop with i = 0 while (< i 1000000000) do (incf i))) 

gcl with Rords's code:
>(load "count-to-billion.cl")
Loading count-to-billion.cl
real-time : 595.667 secs
run time : 595.667 secs

>(compile-file "count-to-billion.cl")
OPTIMIZE levels: Safety=0 (No runtime error checking), Space=0, Speed=3
Finished compiling count-to-billion.cl.
#p"count-to-billion.o"

>(load "count-to-billion")
Loading count-to-billion.o
real time : 575.567 secs
run time  : 575.567 secs
start address -T 1020e400 Finished loading count-to-billion.o
48
```

**UPDATE 3:**

This is the last one, I promise. I tried Rords other code:

```
(defun billion-test ()
  (loop with i fixnum = 0
        while (< i 1000000000) do (incf i)))
```

and suprisingly, it runs as fast Joswig's the difference being the keywords `fixnum` and
`with`:

`gcl`'s output:

```
real time : 0.850 secs
run time  : 0.850 secs
```

`sbcl`'s output(ran for about half a second and spat this out):

```
debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {23FC3A39}>:
  The value 536870912 is not of type FIXNUM.
```

`clisp`'s output:

```
Real time: 302.82532 sec.
Run time: 286.35544 sec.
Space: 11798673420 Bytes
GC: 21413, GC time: 64.47521 sec.
NIL
```

Comment: If I search for `fixnum-safety` in this page, the only occurrence I find of it is in your question;  I don't see it in @RainerJoswig's code.  Are you sure you took his code as it was written?

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: I used it in an earlier version. It is LispWorks-only and not needed here.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Ah, nevermind then.  I saw OP's comment, and it didn't make sense.  I should have checked the revisions. Sorry, Segfault!

Comment: I've switched to 64bit some time ago. Maybe your computer/OS is 64bit capable, too? Then you might want to look for a 64bit Lisp implementation for Windows (I'd guess that SBCL or CCL should have those).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- start up time
- undeclared variable
- global variable
- no type declarations
- compiler not told to optimize
- on 32bit machines/implementations 1000000000 is possibly not a fixnum, see the variable `MOST-POSITIVE-FIXNUM`
- possibly `<` comparison with a bignum on 32bit machines -> better to count to 0
- slow implementation

A 64bit Common Lisp should have larger fixnums and we can use simple fixnum computations.

On a 64bit LispWorks on a MacBook Air laptop with 2 Ghz Intel i7 I get unoptimized code to run in slightly under 2 seconds. If we add declarations, it gets a bit faster.

```
(defun billion-test ()
  (let ((i 0))
    (declare (fixnum i)
             (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0))
             (inline +))
    (loop while (< i 1000000000) do 
          (setq i (+ i 1)))))


CL-USER 7 > (time (billion-test))
Timing the evaluation of (BILLION-TEST)

User time    =        0.973
System time  =        0.002
Elapsed time =        0.958
Allocation   = 154384 bytes
0 Page faults
NIL
```

**A 64bit SBCL needs 0.3 seconds.** So it is even faster.

With GCL you should be able to get better results on a 32bit machine. Here I use GCL on a 32bit ARM processor (Samsung Exynos 5410). A billion is with GCL on the ARM machine still a fixnum.

```
>(type-of 1000000000)

FIXNUM

>(defun billion-test ()
  (let ((i 0))
    (declare (fixnum i)
             (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0))
             (inline +))
    (loop while (< i 1000000000) do 
          (setq i (+ i 1)))))

BILLION-TEST

>(compile *)

Compiling /tmp/gazonk_23351_0.lsp.
Warning:
The OPTIMIZE quality DEBUG is unknown.
End of Pass 1.  
End of Pass 2.  
OPTIMIZE levels: Safety=0 (No runtime error checking), Space=0, Speed=3
Finished compiling /tmp/gazonk_23351_0.lsp.
Loading /tmp/gazonk_23351_0.o
start address -T 0x7a36f0 Finished loading /tmp/gazonk_23351_0.o
#<compiled-function BILLION-TEST>
NIL
NIL
```

Now you can see that GCL is also quite fast, even on a slower ARM processor:

```
>(time (billion-test))

real time       :      0.639 secs
run-gbc time    :      0.639 secs
child run time  :      0.000 secs
gbc time        :      0.000 secs
NIL
```

Comment: Care to add some little explanation and how to fix them?

Comment: `gcl` reports `MOST-POSITIVE-FIXNUM` as 2147483647 while `clisp's` is 16777215. Are bignum comparisons that slow? Why?

Comment: @Segfault: fixnum operations are basically primitive processor instructions. A bignum is much more complicated.

Comment: Unrelated question, how do you compile from the console using `gcl` in windows?

Comment: @Segfault: I have no idea. If you have an unrelated question, you might want to ask it as an unrelated and new question.

Comment: SBCL is quite fast about this even without any declarations. `(time (loop with i = 0 while (< i 1000000000) do (incf i)))` gives `Evaluation took: 0.776 seconds of real time` ...

Comment: And a compiled version in GCL (the code was `(defun billion-test () (loop with i fixnum = 0 while (< i 1000000000) do (incf i)))`) even returns instantly. Apparently the dead code gets eliminated.

Comment: @Rörd, mine is hardly instantaneous. The only way to make it so is through Joswig's additions. What are your system specs?

Comment: @Segfault: Yes, I should have specified that. Since GCL uses the system's C compiler, its optimization behaviour is likely to vary greatly between different configurations. I observed this result on a x86-64 Linux system with GCC 4.73.

Comment: @Segfault: Also note that the code I used with GCL does have a type hint (`with i fixnum`). Without that, it doesn't return instantly for me either. I guess, without it GCC's optimizer cannot recognize the dead code.

Comment: @Rörd, do you mean `with i=0`? That's a type hint?

Comment: @Segfault: The code in my comment on SBCL and my comment on GCL is slightly different. The `with` clause in the `loop` is just `with i = 0` in the first, but `with i fixnum = 0` in the second. That extra `fixnum` there is the type hint.